# Coding Game Level 1 can you help me?

Tags: android, logic

My problem is I don't even can finish the first level

I have 3 Absolute's

Input:1 
Input:-2 
Input:0

The Output must be:
Output:1 
Output:2 
Output:0

I can use `if`, `else`, `return` and `< >`

I try it with:

```
if input < 0 {
    return 2;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

I pass the first and second output with this but not the last one I don't understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use "=="? If yes then:

```
 if input < 0 {
            return 2;
    }
    else if input == 0 {
         return 0;
    }
    else {
         return 1;
    }
```

If you cannot use the equality sign then:

```
if input < 0 {
        return 2;
}
else if input > 0{
     return 1;
}
else{
     return 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Fast answer ! In general your answer will be right :) but the problem it is not allowed to write "else if" because it creates code in code

Comment: Can you just not make another if statement right after?

Comment: @noob4 Your comment is confusing. You're allowed to use if/else/return, but can't write `else if`?
`else if` is syntactically the same as `else { if (whatever) {} }`

Answer (score 0):

There you go ;)

```
if input < 0 
   return 2
else
   return input
```